# QTextStream atEnd() is returning true when starting to read from a file

Tags: qt, file, qtextstream

I want to read and parse contents of the /proc/PID/status file on a linux machine, but the QTextStream.atEnd is always returning true when starting to read. The code:

```
QString procDirectory = "/proc/";
    procDirectory.append(QString::number(PID));
    procDirectory.append("/status");
    QFile inputFile(procDirectory);
    if (inputFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
    {
        QTextStream in(&inputFile);
        QString line;

        while (!in.atEnd())
        {
            line = in.readLine();
```

File exists and if I read lines manually without the while expression, the files are read normally.

Did I miss something obvious?

(Debian 8 x64, QT 5.4.1 x64, gcc 4.9.2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preferred way oft looping over these streams is with a do/while loop. This is for allowing the stream to detect Unicode correctly before any queries (like atEnd) are made.

```
QTextStream stream(stdin);
QString line;
do {
    line = stream.readLine();
} while (!line.isNull());
```

Comment: Thank you! Will use do while then.

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind found out I needed to read one line before the while clause, now it works.