# "while(!in.atEnd())" returns true with every file

Tags: c++, qt, qfile, qtextstream

I'm opening a directory, then take files with `*.cpp` and `*.h` extensions. Then I try to read them line by line in order to scan for some info and write it in another file, but `while` returns `true` and never starts.

```cpp
QString output = "out.txt";

QFile file(output);
if (QFile(output).exists())
{
    QFile::remove(output);
}
if (file.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite))
{
    QTextStream out(&file);
    out << directory << endl;

    QDir dir(directory);
    dir.setFilter(QDir::Files);
    QFileInfoList list = dir.entryInfoList();
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); ++i) {
        QFileInfo fileInfo = list.at(i);

        if (fileInfo.suffix() == "cpp" || fileInfo.suffix() == "h")
        {
            out << fileInfo.fileName() << endl;

            QFile target(fileInfo.fileName());

            if (target.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
            {
                QTextStream in(&target);
                while(!in.atEnd())
                {
                    QString str = in.readLine();
                    out << str << endl;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
system("notepad.exe out.txt");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was trying to read files in the local directory, because I was trying to open them by their names instead of their paths. Here's the solution:

```cpp
QFile target(fileInfo.fileName()); -> QFile target(fileInfo.absoluteFilePath());
```

Comment: You should not use `atEnd()` like that anyway. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/30421132 Even the documentation doesn't use it to iterate through the stream.